Magento 2 : Special price From and To Date Calendar not Showing
I am using 2.4.6-p6,
when I try to set the From and To date inside the special price form the calendar is not showing.
However, I have other custom product attributes of type calendar, and working fine and the calendar also showing.
There is no error in the log file or inside the browser console.
I already all the basic Magento commands including below commands
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush


Have you run compile commands and then check.

yes as I mentioned I run all basic commands rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/* bin/magento s:up bin/magento s:d:c bin/magento s:s:d -f bin/magento ind:rei bin/magento c:f

Can you please share the screenshot.

@SanjayJethva here is the screen share of issue https://imgur.com/a/v41yiGS
